# If the csv file is more than 3 lines, edit it to delete the first line (Not save as new file)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Im trying to code if the csv file is more than 3 lines, edit it to delete the first line.

I want to delete the first line from the existing file instead of saving it as a new file.

For this reason, I had to delete the existing file and create a file with the same name but
only one line is saved and the comma disappears.

I'm using Pandas data frame. But if it doesn't matter if I don't use it, I don't want to use it

Function name might be weird because I'm a beginner

Thanks.

```
file = open("./csv/selllist.csv", encoding="ANSI")
reader = csv.reader(file)
lines= len(list(reader))


if lines > 3:
    df = pd.read_csv('./csv/selllist.csv', 'r+', encoding="ANSI")
    dfa = df.iloc[1:]
    
    print(dfa)

    with open("./csv/selllist.csv", 'r+', encoding="ANSI") as x:
        x.truncate(0)
    with open('./csv/selllist.csv', 'a', encoding="ANSI", newline='') as fo:  
        # Pass the CSV  file object to the writer() function
        wo = writer(fo)
        # Result - a writer object
        # Pass the data in the list as an argument into the writerow() function
        wo.writerow(dfa)  
        # Close the file object
        fo.close()
print()
```

This is the type of csv file I deal with

```
string, string, string, string, string
string, string, string, string, string 
string, string, string, string, string
string, string, string, string, string
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a 2-step approach.

Open the file for reading and count the number of lines. If there are more than 3 lines, re-open the file (for writing) and update it.

For example:

```
lines = []
with open('./csv/selllist.csv') as csv:
  lines = csv.readlines()
if len(lines) > 3:
  with open('./csv/selllist.csv', 'w') as csv:
    for line in lines[1:]: # skip first line
      csv.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas`, you can just specify `header=None` while reading and writing:

```
import pandas as pd

if lines > 3:
    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None)
    df.iloc[1:].to_csv("data.csv", header=None, index=None)
```

With the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open("data.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    lines = list(reader)
    
if len(lines)>3:
    with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerows(lines[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

With one `open` call and using `seek` and `truncate`.

### Setup

```
out = """\
Look at me
I'm a file
for sure
4th line, woot!"""
with open('filepath.csv', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(out)
```

---

### Solution

I'm aiming to minimize the stuff I'm doing.  I'll only open one file and only one time.  I'll only split one time.

```
with open('filepath.csv', 'r+') as csv:
    top, rest = csv.read().split('\n', 1)  # Only necessary to pop off first line
    if rest.count('\n') > 1:               # If 4 or more lines, there will be at
                                           # least two more newline characters

        csv.seek(0)                        # Once we're done reading, we need to
                                           # go back to beginning of file

        csv.truncate()                     # truncate to reduce size of file as well
        csv.write(rest)
```